# Service Bus 1.0 for Windows Server 2008 R2 behind Vault

Tags: azure, servicebus

I am developing Service Bus 1.0 messaging component. For this I am using on-premise Windows Server 2008 R2 (a.k.a. WS2008R2 afterwards) machine which is isolated using Vault and my laptop is connected to this Vault. I can ping WS2008R2 machine and able to do RDP. WS2008R2 machine is not in the same domain in which my laptop is. WS2008R2 is connected to internet using Proxy server and website access restriction is in place.

To start with I am executing service bus 1.0 sample code available [here](http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2012/11/18/connect-service-bus-windows-remote-machine.aspx). My problem is code underlined throws exception:

```
//Set up the queue
QueueDescription queue;
if (namespaceManager.QueueExists(QueueName))
```

---------------------Exception log---------------------

System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing 'https://machine.domain:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace/$STS/OAuth/'. Token provider returned message: '

---

Following HTML is generated from above exception. Above exception returns html content.

This Page Cannot Be Displayed

Based on your corporate access policies, access to this web site ( [https//] machine.domain /) has been blocked.

If you have questions, please contact your corporate network administrator and provide the codes shown below.

**Notification codes:**

```
(1, POLICY, BLOCK-CONNECT, 0x04124770, 1354100172.373, QAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAyf8AAf8AAAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=,(https//)machine.domain/)
```

I am not able to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That error is returned when the gateway process is not able to get a token for the user in the token. This is normally the case when the account the gateway is running as (by default, the user that was running the installer) is on a different domain than the caller.

Can you check which credentials are you using to create the token provider on this line?

```
var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateOAuthTokenProvider(connBuilder.StsEndpoints, new NetworkCredential("SBUser", "P@ssword1", ServerFQDN));
```

Given the restrictions you mention in your environment, make sure that you're passing an account that the server machine knows about (either a local account, or from the domain the server machine belongs to) and not an account from the client machine's domain.